# count query - how to get relation instead of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model structure like this:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :forum

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :post_links
  has_many :links, ->{ uniq }, through: :post_links, dependent: :destroy

class PostLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :link

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_links
  has_many :posts, ->{ uniq }, through: :post_links, dependent: :destroy
```

Now I want to get all Links from Forum with id = 1, sorted by how often they show up in posts in this forum.

```
Link.joins(posts: [topic: :forum]).where("forums.id = ?",1).group("links.id").order("count_all DESC").count
```

It gives me hash like `{140 => 10, 12 => 9, 137 => 8}`

I'd like to have `Link` relation instead of hash with ids, but I'm not sure how to change this query.

Comment: You needed the count of it too?, whats the o/p you are getting removing the count

Comment: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "count_all" does not exist`. I don't need a count, just want to order it by count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with this query:

```
Link.joins(posts: [topic: :forum]).where("forums.id = ?",1)
       .group("links.id").order("count_links_id DESC")
       .select("links.*, COUNT(links.id) AS count_links_id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `select` in the query should return an ActiveRecord::Relation. Try this:

`Link.select("links.*, COUNT(links.id) as link_count").joins(posts: [topic: :forum]).where("forums.id = ?",1).group("links.id").order("link_count DESC").count`

Since I don't have your model structure and relations I can't test this, but I did it with a similar query. Using `select`you will get a Relation. 
`links.*` will return all columns/attributes of the Link model. In case you only need specific attributes (like the url of the link) just use `link.url` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are fetching the count form the maximum grouped `ID's` you cannot directly get the active record relation but,

You can just fire a `where` condition in the `Link model` from the returned result to get the `Active record association`,

```
Link.where(id: (Link.joins(posts: [topic: :forum]).where("forums.id = ?",1).group("links.id").order("count_all DESC").count).keys)
```

Returns,

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Link...]
```

Comment: Yep, but it probably does not guarantee correct links order.

Comment: It will give the result which you needed, sorted by how often they show up in posts depending on the group_by clause, please execute this code.

Comment: Yep it does not keep the order, as outer query is `SELECT links.* FROM links where links.id IN (114, 101, 25 ... all ids)` and results of this query are links sorted by id.